# COPY array from one structure to another

Tags: c

```
  struct task_inst task_list[NUM_OF_TASKS] = {
    {task, 3, 0, 20, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 3, 1, 20, 550, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 3, 2, 20, 600, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 3, 3, 20, 650, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 1, 4, 10, 350, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 1, 5, 10, 375, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 2, 6, 10, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 2, 7, 10, 425, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 };

 struct queue_insti queue_list[6] = {
    {task, 3, 0, 20, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 3, 1, 20, 550, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 3, 2, 20, 600, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 3, 3, 20, 650, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 2, 0, 0,  0,   0, 0, 0, 0},
    {task, 2, 0, 0,  0,   0, 0, 0, 0}  
 };
```

I need to copy tasks 4 and 5 if it satisfies a condition  and if not 6 and 7 from the first structure to the second. It must be copied to the last two array of the second structure which command should i use to do that?

Comment: iam using embedded c. the first structure contains eight tasks to be performed.the first four task run constantly where as the the last four two tasks are performed when the clock tick is odd and other two when its even.6 tasks are performed at time t.

Comment: You can copy a struct using assignment. What are you having difficulty with? What have you tried?

Comment: @user3642146 This is nearly impossible to read ;-)

Comment: is there any other way to send you the code

Comment: yhe command i used was task_list[4] =Queue_list[4] for which i got a error stating its uncompatible.

Comment: Well, that `task_list[4] =Queue_list[4]` doesn't work doesn't surprise me, after all `task_inst` and `queue_insti` are different types... Just change one to the type of the other, and it should work fine. If that is not an option, there's probably something wrong with your design.

Comment: how about task_list[4] = (task_inst)Queue_list[4];  although my preference is to bypass the type attributes I.E.:  memcpy( &task_list[4], (task_inst*)Queue_list[4], sizeof( task_inst ) );  Note, if the associated struct definitions only have a tag, then the code would be: memcpy( (struct task_inst*)taskList[4], (struct task_inst*)Queue_list[4], sizeof( struct task_inst ) );